# RxJava2: Subscription not reached

Tags: rx-java

I've created this subscription that creates another subscription:

```
this.loggingInterval$
    .filter(interval -> interval > 0)
    .doAfterNext(
        interval ->
        {
            Observable.interval(interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .doOnNext(t -> this.readAdditionalConfigurationFile())
                .doOnError(t -> LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).error(t.toString()))
                .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
                .subscribe();
        }
    )
    .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    .subscribe();
```

So, each time the `interval` changes and it's greater than 0 I build another subscription reading configuration file each new `interval` seconds. It's destroyed when `destroy$` emits `true`.

The problem is `interval.doOnNext()` is never reached.

```
this.destroy$ = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(false);
this.loggingInterval$ = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(10);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an antipattern to create a subscription within an observable; there's many easier ways to do it.

```
this
.loggingInterval$
.filter(interval -> interval > 0)
.distinctUntilChanged()
.switchMap(interval -> Observable.interval(interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io()))
.doOnNext(dummy -> this.readAdditionalConfigurationFile())
.doOnError(t -> LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).error(t.toString()))
.takeUntil(this.destroy$)
.subscribe();
```

The above also has the benefit of terminating the whole chain if the subscription gets unsubscribed (which is what your destroy$ is supposed to do, right?).

Comment: Yeah! It's looks really fine! Nevertheless, I've to comment another thing. I've edited the post.

Comment: So, the `BehaviorSubject<>` for the logging interval is actually the "right" way to do changing values that are f.e. exposed via JMX. But the `destroy$` is a bit smelly, you could replace it with a plaing `private boolean destroy;` and just `.takeUntil(dummy -> destroy)` - or just unsubscribe from the subscription.